# Possibility of Gupshup and Adalo Integration

Tags: one-time-password, sms-verification

Can Gupshup be integrated with Adalo for OTP verification via SMS. I can see that it can't be done via Zapier so wanted to confirm if there is a way around it because Adalo's custom action feature can't yet use the return values of custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate collection (Call it “Login activity”)
2. In the login screen, add an action to create a Login activity record with an automatic field for verification code
3. In Integromat, listen to create records for this collection and send a SMS using Twilio.

Trying to figure out how to change the login screen on “Send OTP” to show an OTP input field. This should accept the OTP and if it matches, should login the user. Will update this thread if I find a way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).